# NSXMLParser Memory Leak from Second Parse Call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsxmlparser

**Update:** While the Leaks instrument points to the first call to `[parser parse];`, I have identified that the leak only occurs when I make this call a second time.  I don't see anything in the NSXMLParser class reference or documentation which indicates that one can't re-parse.  Am I missing something?  Should I create a new NSXMLParser for each time that I wish to parse the document?

I am currently trying to track down a leak in my xml parsing code for an iPhone app.  I've searched through other posts on leaks with NSXMLParser, but haven't found any answers that I could use, so I would really appreciate help.

The instruments Leaks tool is detecting a leak in the following code:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"collisionGraph" ofType: @"graphml"]];
NSXMLParser* parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data] autorelease];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];    <<<<< leak here according to Leaks
self.currentPass++;

...

[parser parse];
self.currentPass++;
```

I removed all of the code from my delegate callback methods, but this didn't stop the leak.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
   attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
}  

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
}
```

Here is the view in Instruments http://i22.photobucket.com/albums/b311/Erithil/ParserLeak.png (linked because I don't have the rep to post images).

I'm really stumped by this, so any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you call release on your NSXMLParser object?  Can you verify using a debugger or a logging statement that your code to call release is actually being run?  -[NSXMLParser parse] may be allocating memory that it expects to clean up when the parser gets deallocated.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks Ryan.  One of my co-workers also suggested that the parser might be leaking because the autorelease pool might not be releasing in a timely manner.  I tested replacing the 'autorelease' call with a call to '[parser release];' at the end of the method.  Using the debugger, I confirmed that the release call was being made.  Nevertheless, the leak was still present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a leak within NSXMLParser (if e.g. xmlCleanupParser() is not called on the underlying libxml) or reusable memory mistakenly flagged as a leak. I think it's what typically happens with parsers due to them reusing (and not properly releasing?) their allocated memory.

Comment: I see.  Is there a way to firmly determine whether the leak is real (and if not to tell Leaks to ignore it), or should I just workaround this by using separate NSXMLParser objects?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think NSXMLParser has any provision for being asked to parse a document twice.  The expectation is that you would create, parse, then destroy.